# How to prevent AndroidStudio add Symbolic BreakPoints automatically

Tags: android-studio

I hava a project with some C/C++ code, and I need to debug them.

When I add a line BreakPoint in my code and start the Debugger,the Debugger always suspend at some system C++ code like the picture below. This means I have to click the [Resume Program] button dozens of times before I get to where I actually need to hang.
[Debugger was suspend at system code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBj6R.png)

When I click the line BreakPoint I had added, it's show that there a Symbolic BreakPoint here and cause Debugger suspend the code execution. But I didn't add Symbolic BreakPoint before!
[Symbolic BreakPoint add automatically](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gB02C.png)

So, I delete the Symbolic BreakPoint, but it take no effects at this debug session, the Debugger will still always suspend at some system C++ code! And once I relaunch the Debugger, the Symbolic BreakPoint that I had deleted has been added back! I still have to click the [Resume Program] button dozens of times.

It really bother me and I can't debug the code with this situation.

What I have try:

1. I have restart my phone, reinstall the applicaiton, invalidate and restart AndroidStudio, restart my computer.
2. Switch from click the Debug button directly to using Attach Debugger to Process.
3. Delete the automatic added Symbolic BreakPoint and add a custom Symbolic BreakPoint.

The above action take no effects. I wish I could remove this breakpoint and using the Debugger as normal.

About my phone:
[Phone Information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8PTZ.png)

About my computer:
[Computer Information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHZqC.png)

About my AndroidStudio:

```
Android Studio Hedgehog | 2023.1.1 Patch 2
Build #AI-231.9392.1.2311.11330709, built on January 19, 2024
Runtime version: 17.0.7+0-17.0.7b1000.6-10550314 aarch64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 13.6
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 12288M
Cores: 10
Metal Rendering is ON
Registry:
    external.system.auto.import.disabled=true
    debugger.new.tool.window.layout=true
    ide.text.editor.with.preview.show.floating.toolbar=false
    ide.instant.shutdown=false
    performance.watcher.unresponsive.interval.ms=1000
    vcs.log.index.git=false
    ide.experimental.ui=true
```